# Replacing �'s with quotations and apostrophes

Tags: html

Recently I've done some careless copying and pasting into my html documents. Because the document type is set to Strict, the quotation marks and apostrophes show up as this crazy symbol: �.
Example: Brad says, �Don�t rock the boat baby.�

I considered changing the document type from Strict (which could turn out to be the easiest thing to do) but I'm not sure if changing from Strict would have any negative repercussions.

Naturally, I need to get rid of them. The problem is that I need to replace A LOT of them from a lot of different documents. I'd use the replace feature on Textpad, but it doesn't recognize � , so I can't change it. I've been reduced to going through all of the code and doing the tedious replacing.

Does anyone know of a good way to replace these things? It could be some other software, or anything else really.

Comment: This is an encoding problem, not some problem with "strictness" (of what, by the way? HTML doctype?).

Comment: FYI, if you didn't know already, the characters in your post are all U+FFFD. There's no difference between the quotes and apostrophes. I don't know if Stack Overflow transformed it or if your source is like that, too.

Answer (score 0):

I always use textmate on the Mac to replace them because it does recognize those characters. Try notepad++ and a bunch of different text editors and see what you come up with.

I remember dealing with this when I first started out and my secretary got reprimanded for such a crime.

Comment: Well that's helpful. I'll try that.

Comment: @Bradley, did you fix this issue? Come up with a better solution than mine?